# powershell ping continous for specific duration and save log

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell
when searching for test my internet connection i found this simple code

```
    ping google.com -t | Select-String "Reply" | foreach $_ { $a = Get-Date$a.ToString() + " " + $_ } | Out-File  "C:\users\"your account"\Documents\pingLog$((get-date).tostring("HHmmss")).txt"
```

try it and success but i want to set ping for specific duration say about 30 minutes or 1 hour so i try modified the code with this

```
     $stopTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(30)
     $results = do {
     $now = Get-Date
     ping google.com -t | Select-String "Reply" | foreach $_ { $a = Get-Date
     $a.ToString() + " " + $_ } 
     } 
     until ($now -ge $stopTime)

     $results | Out-File  "C:\users\"your account"\Documents\pingLog$((get-date).tostring("HHmmss")).txt"
```

but no result or output to txt.

i just want to ping for about 30 minutes or 1 hours and stop, save the result(not only reply but include rto and unreachable) to log and schedule it with task schedule.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering.  Do you have a reason why don't you use *Task Scheduler* for the scheduling?  Just run the script and schedule it to run whenever you like.

Comment: before using task schedule, i try the modified script first but failed to output log so i need help about what wrong with the code

Comment: See my answer - don't forget to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember always a golden rule:  Be **always** careful with **time**!  (comparing times/zones, looking into past/future, timestamps etc.).

Also it is wise not to use extraneous variables.  The output can be redirected directly in the script (see the example).

Your script has an issue with the `ping -t`.  That specifies that it should query the server till ctrl+break is specified.  The default behaviour of `ping` command on windows is to spit out 4 replies.  You can change that beaviour with `-n` parameter - the looping is done via powershell.  There is no need to use `-t` for the internal `ping` loop.

I would use `New-TimeSpan` which gives you minutes difference if you use `.minutes`

### **Edit** further simplification of the script

Now you don't need to add any time just check if current time is within the limit.  I have added also the real time of running the script (you can get different time stamp from `ping` command).

```
 # 1 minute
 $limit_in_minutes = 1
 # path to log
 $log_file = '<path_to_log>\time.log'
 # clear the log file before running again
 fc > $log_file

 $start_timer = Get-Date
 Do {
    $current_time = Get-Date
    ping google.com -n 1 | Select-String "Reply" | foreach $_ { $a = Get-Date; $a.ToString() + " " + $_ } | Out-File -Append -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath  $log_file
    # normally the output of New-TimeSpan is a String but you need an Integer to be able to compare it
    $running_minutes = [int]((New-TimeSpan –Start $start_timer –End $current_time).minutes) 
    $running_seconds = [int]((New-TimeSpan –Start $start_timer –End $current_time).seconds) 
    Write-Output  "Running for: $($running_minutes)m:$($running_seconds)s" | Out-File -Append -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath  $log_file
 } Until ($running_minutes -ge $limit_in_minutes)
```

Here is shortened log file:

```
   11.09.2018 16:10:35 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:0s
    11.09.2018 16:10:35 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:0s
    11.09.2018 16:10:35 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:0s
    11.09.2018 16:10:35 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:0s
    11.09.2018 16:10:36 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:0s
    11.09.2018 16:10:36 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:1s
    11.09.2018 16:10:36 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:1s
    11.09.2018 16:10:36 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:1s
    11.09.2018 16:10:36 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
    Running for: 0m:1s

...

Running for: 0m:58s
11.09.2018 16:11:33 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:58s
11.09.2018 16:11:34 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:58s
11.09.2018 16:11:34 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:59s
11.09.2018 16:11:34 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:59s
11.09.2018 16:11:34 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:59s
11.09.2018 16:11:34 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:59s
11.09.2018 16:11:35 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=57
Running for: 0m:59s
11.09.2018 16:11:35 Reply from 172.217.168.78: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=57
Running for: 1m:0s
```

Comment: try the script set $user_time_period = 1 for 1 minutes, but scipt don't stop after 1 minutes also seems this is reuse log and not create new log with specific datetime name

Comment: @CliffLawa I always try to run the scripts before posting them - it worked for me.    See my edit, I have further simplified the script and added a log file (the log file is always overwritten - tested).