# Windows batch script to ping for one hour

Tags: batch-file, ping

I have found a multitude of sources to ping *every* hour, but I'm finding it difficult to get info on how to ping for a period of one hour. I'm currently going with this:

```
ping -nS 3600 8.8.8.8
```

Which pings every second for the 3600 seconds in one hour, but I feel like there should be a way to actually specify one hour's length since this would actually go over one hour if there are timeouts. That actually isn't a huge problem for what I need, but my OCD is kicking in and needs things to be exact.

Comment: add `-w 1000` as well to limit the time to wait for reply to 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

Comment: It might also help if you explain what you want to do exactly

Comment: I work in the Network Operations Center of a cloud provider; there is a firewall pair that is throwing off high availability fault alerts and I'm currently required to run this test whenever it does. If it fails for more then five min at a time, I contact an on-call engineer. That's about it. Someday, I hope, they will replace the firewall, but it could be a while before that happens.

Comment: Seeing as you are working for a cloud provider I am really surprised your company is not using a network monitoring tool for things like this. You might want to consider using a program like [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/) to do this.  There are others out there of course.  I am just listing this one as this is the one my company uses.

Comment: You realise that ICMP is simply diagnostic protocol and gets no priority? If the firewall is busy with other more important things you will discard packets even though there are no real issues. It is just busy with better things to do than respond to icmp. There are much better ways to track issues.

Comment: This [powershell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275000) may be useful to you.

Comment: ok, I understand. So do you simply want to test if it fails for 5 minutes or longer at any time?